# $.each Not Working other than fire fox 3.6

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a json as below

```
 {"DataList":
  {"Data":[
    {"@attributes":{"description":"FGFGFGH","code":"FGFGFGH"}},
    {"@attributes":{"description":"UIS default relying party","code":"UIS"}},
    {"@attributes":{"description":"MDEx Healthcare Portal","code":"MDE"}},
    {"@attributes":{"description":"VBK","code":"VBK"}},
    {"@attributes":{"description":"Omnicare","code":"OC"}},
    {"@attributes":{"description":"MDEX","code":"MDEX"}},
    {"@attributes":{"description":"Bank of America","code":"BOA"}},
    {"@attributes":{"description":"LDAP","code":"LDAP"}},
    {"@attributes":{"description":"JetBlue","code":"JB"}},
    {"@attributes":{"description":"Digital Signature Demo Application","code":"DEMODS"}}
      ]
  }
}
```

and i am below jquery code to create select box options

```
$.each(response, function(i, DataList) {
                $.each(DataList,function(j,Data){
                    var finalObj = Data.@attributes;
                    options += '<option value="' + finalObj.code + '">' + finalObj.description + '</option>';
                });
                $("#relyingpartyall").html(options); 
            });
```

The above code is working fine in firefox 3.6 but in firefox 10,11 , chrome,safari and ie its not working it gives the following error.

```
Firefox 11 : can't convert AttributeName to string ,var finalObj = Data.@attributes;

      Chrome : Unexpected Identifier @ line "options += '<option value="' + finalObj.code + '">' + finalObj.description + '</option>';"
```

can anybody help me on this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

Try like this:

```
var finalObj = Data["@attributes"];
```

or directly access the Data array in a single `$.each`:

```
var relyingpartyall = $('#relyingpartyall');
relyingpartyall.empty();
$.each(response.DataList.Data, function(i, item) {
    var attributes = item["@attributes"];
    relyingpartyall.append(
        $('<option/>', {
            value: attributes.code,
            html: attributes.description
        })
    );
});
​
```

Comment: I am getting two different response like below
Type 1 :
`{"DataList":{"Data":{"@attributes":{"description":"FGFGFGH","code":"FGFGFGH"}}}}`

Type 2 :
`{"DataList":{"Data":[
{"@attributes":{"description":"FGFGFGH","code":"FGFGFGH"}},
{"@attributes":{"description":"UIS default relying party","code":"UIS"}}]}}`

For second type ur code working fine but for the first response it wont work. 
:(

Comment: @TechieSathish, yes it won't work because in the first example `Data` is not an array. It's a poor way to represent multiple items using properties. In this case you should keep your original loops or if you have control over the generation of the JSON fix it so that you always have Data as an array.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The response I am generating by using the json_encode php function.